# Как в Yii2 создать ссылку и action в таком ввиде?

Tags: php, yii2

www.test.ru/watch?v=ZkbeQhELghy

Comment: watch создается как обычный экшн, а остальное входные параметры

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте

Для реализации такого роута достаточно в SiteController добавить:

```
public function actionWatch($v)
{
    // somecode
}
```

P.S. Возможно еще необходимо будет настроить [UrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html), если Вы еще этого не сделали.

Comment: А генерация ссылки будет такая: Url::to(['site/wath', 'v' => 'ZkbeQhELghy'])

Comment: С этим разобрался, только как бд генерировать при сохранения поста под таким id ZfeMhKdrJ и.т.д чтобы не повторялись, какая нужна функция.

Comment: @RustemS Используй Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();